# Where can I get documentation for Google Chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, documentation, manual

The official [Chrome extensions documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions) seems terribly out of date. For example, [this page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview.html#contentScripts) references `chrome.tabs.getSelected() method`, which has been deprecated long ago (one should use `chrome.tabs.query()` now).

The [samples page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html) is also outdated. Almost none of the samples I checked worked.

So, naturally, I wonder, when can one get relevant documentation on Google Chrome extensions?

Comment: The docs are auto-generated to ensure that the API documentation itself is up-to-date (latest stable release). Parts of the documentation have to be edited manually, such as explanations on some concepts. Can you give concrete examples of samples which do not work?

Comment: You can search for `getSelected` on the linked page to see all the examples that use this outdated method, for example.

Comment: Some examples may be outdated (especially/mainly those which are still using manifest version 1), but is not a problem. The main docs are sufficient to learn to write Chrome extensions. Whenever you encounter an "undocumented" feature, search in [What's New](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/whats_new.html) for the API, and you'll see deprecation details + alternatives. If still in doubt, search on Stack Overflow for code snippets / answers (within the google-chrome-extension tag).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [API documentation](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index.html) should be current. If you want something more tutorial-like the other pages are useful but you should cross-check with the API reference since you are correct that the APIs still change relatively often.

Answer (score -1):

http://tutorialzine.com/2010/06/making-first-chrome-extension/ might be a good place to start.